# Getting Decoding Error with Accented, Latin Characters Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, products, rest-api, character-encoding

I'm trying to create products via the REST API but in the body of the request I send accented characters (á, é, ñ, etc) and I get a decoding error as a response, I have configured postman to send the request with UTF-8 encoding, but I still get that error, apache is also set with UTF-8 encoding as well.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Workaround is to decode product names before sending to Rest API:

```
var product_name_encoded = product_name.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/g, function(i) {
  return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
```